# What does $U(y)$ mean in an equation

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am reading a book on probability (*Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes* by A. Papoulis) and lets just say that notation is not its strong suit.

Lately this symbol has been popping up. I know that $X \sim U(a,b)$ means that the random variable $X$ is uniformly distributed at $(a,b)$, but I can't understand what it means in an equation.

> **e.g** (from a problem in the book)
>
> $$f_{Y}(y) = e^{-y}U(y)$$

Comment: In modern probability textbooks, random variables are usually capitalised, whereas small letters are rather used for *realisations* of these random variables.

Comment: I know but I do not think that this is applicable here since there is no random variable u

Comment: You've written "random variable x".

Comment: Oh I see what you meant. Edited the question

Comment: Please use MathJax for math expressions so that [your question is correctly parsed by the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22026/290189).  Btw, you may consider using [blockquotes `>` in Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#blockquote) for quoting external contents.

Comment: $U(y)$ here might be the unit step function

Answer (score 0):

Without having the text at hand:

1. It could be that they mean the density function of a random variable which is distributed according to $U(a,b)$.
2. Depending on context it could be a different function $U$, but I'd doubt that.

Are the two $U$'s written the same way? Sometimes the "distribution-naming" letters are written with more fancy, e.g. $\mathcal{U}$ (or similar).

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: I do not see how U(y) defines a uniform distribution. What is the interval if that is the case?

Comment: That would be dependent on the context. If I was speaking about a random variable $x \sim U(a,b)$ and in the next line there appeared the function you were talking about, I would assume we are still talking about $U(a,b)$ (with $a,b$ either as general variables or concrete values).

Comment: In the problem $X$ is a random variable with $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y = -ln X$ is another random variable. $f_{Y}(y)$ is the density of $Y$

Comment: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.  Please use [math markup for each math expression](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22026/290189) to ensure the correct parsing of your content.

Comment: I'd still wager that $U$ is the density function of the uniformly distributed variable $X$ and that it is $U(y)$ (instead of $U(x)$) is simply because the density function $f_Y(y)$ takes $y$ as the argument. Even more so because $Y = ln(X)$ and thus the $e^y$ makes sense now.

Comment: So you'd say that it is $f_Y (y) = e^{-y} U(y) = e^{-y} \frac{1}{1-0} = e^{-y} \cdot 1 = e^{-y}$? Then why write $e^{-y} U(y)$ in the first place?

Comment: Imagine $a = 2, b = 10$, then $U(y) = \frac{1}{10-2} = \frac{1}{8}$. It's just a coincidence that the fraction resolves to being $1$ here.

Comment: If everything is clear(er) to you, I'd be happy if you would accept my answer (by clicking on the tick mark below the voting options).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time but I had the same ideas, and I still don't think that this is what the text is trying to say